# Unable to increase heap size for jmeter on mac M1

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, stress-testing

Whenever I am running more than 4000 threads, the jemter test run throws
`Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread in thread Thread[StandardJMeterEngine,5,main]. See log file for details.`

Is there a way to increase heap size of JMeter in Mac OSX? I have tried editing the jmeter.bat and jmter.sh file, but it didn't help.

`set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m`

Does any one know how to do it in Mac OSX.

Answer (score 0):

It's neither connected with JMeter or Java, it's your operating system who limits the maximum number of processes which can be created by a single user. I believe you should raise this question in the https://apple.stackexchange.com/ community.

Check out [Mac OS X … “fork: Resource temporarily unavailable”](http://blog.ghostinthemachines.com/2010/01/19/mac-os-x-fork-resource-temporarily-unavailable/) article for hints on how to increase the number.

`sudo launchctl limit maxproc` command should give you the current limit and the possibility to amend it.

More information: [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling)